# IE8 CSS Menu Fix

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

**IE8 CSS Menu Fix**

I have a website CSS menu that is not working on IE8.
Code working fine with Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>broken in ie8</title>
<style>
ul#mrmenu,ul#mrmenu ul{
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    }
ul#mrmenuxx,ul#mrmenu .submenu{
    border:1px solid yellow;
    border-right:medium none;
    }
ul#mrmenu .submenu{
    background:black;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    opacity:0;
    float:left;
    padding:0 10px;
    }
ul#mrmenu li:hover>.submenu{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    }
ul#mrmenu li{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    float:left;
    }
ul#mrmenu li:hover{
    z-index:1;
    }
ul#mrmenu ul .submenu{
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
    }
ul#mrmenu{
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
    zoom:1;
    padding:0 0;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height:47px;
    }
ul#mrmenu .column{
    float:left;
    }
* html ul#mrmenu li a, * html ul#mrmenu li label{
    display:inline-block;
    }
ul#mrmenu>li{
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    }
ul#mrmenu li.toplast{
    width:15%;
    }
ul#mrmenu a:active, ul#mrmenu a:focus, ul#mrmenu label:active, ul#mrmenu label:focus{
    outline-style:none;
    }
ul#mrmenu a, ul#mrmenu label{
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:left;
    font:bold 12px Trebuchet MS;
    line-height: 18px;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    }
ul#mrmenu .submenu .column{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
ul#mrmenu ul li{
    float:none;
    margin:2px 0 0;
    }
ul#mrmenu ul a, ul#mrmenu ul label{
    text-align:left;
    padding:2px;
    padding-left:10px;
    }
ul#mrmenu img{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:6px;
    }
ul#mrmenu span{
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    background-position:right center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:0px;
    }
ul#mrmenu ul span{
    padding-right:8px;
    }
ul#mrmenu ul li:hover>a,ul#mrmenu ul li a.pressed, ul#mrmenu ul li:hover>label,ul#mrmenu ul li label.pressed{
    background-image:none;
    color:#yellow;
    }
.mr-button {
    background: black;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    border-width:1px 1px 1px 0;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:14px 10px;
}
.mr-button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
#mrmenu {
    color: #cfcfcf;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="mrmenu" class="topmenu">
   <li class="mr-button">
      <label><span>Menu1</span></label>
      <div class="submenu">
         <div class="column">
            <ul class="cat_parent">
               <li>
                  <label>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
                  Item1</label>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <label>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
                  Item2</label>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <label>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABUAAAAVCAYAAACpF6WWAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwwAADsMBx2+oZAAAABZ0RVh0Q3JlYXRpb24gVGltZQAxMS8xMi8xMhR8XRwAAAAYdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEZpcmV3b3Jrc0+zH04AAAPTSURBVDiNnZRbiFVVGMd/3z57nzPn5oyjjjU0Y5qXBBNKm2maLAsberMLRahFSBdRhPCheht88UGIgiiash4SjC5SQokPFTGUEuaF0cRKhazp6MyZ+zlnn3P2WvvrYe/BSYzKDxYsvrXWj//6r+9boqpc3Cm5RJI33Vzz0+Km+b+hxseURj+wdba192pJiq/i+VXeyLcseCGfz+EQAooqqP4XpKDiUCqVmBr6rS/dwHY5u4MVze1zf5zX5KXqhQJBCRwPvBS4aSABhP/CdYDsjQxPBrXRi8XVrg9Z1/gpJkYwbT3UZncjfgF//ALh5WMkgxFyaXCmXbmW+hCoXMY16VTEA5VaGQLIdN5DZuVWKBewtQphtUTtj5OMDewjOXKMfA7w/gFMiNTKGFDXGghtLKJeAX8YTA1JN5FI5ck2zie7/EFKpw8xduR18tU/cbPXsEQjjjXgWgNYoAFk4H349XNItyCtnWhrF8xdgRKQX/UotfZVTH35EvmxYxFY/w5lJnRaqSkMYf0hEu5Z3DP9SNMsWNgDdzxH2LSE5Jw2nMf3MLV/G7OGD5OYqXiGUsfaeKEO1da7mLz9ecYXrGM0zFEtTMLxT5HPnkEufou6GdxZc8k+9hbl3GK0Ep+dMawFxxpQA5Qg17GBeZv6aN70HpnNh/A7tjNeT6JDBeTAFuTcQVQ8ko3z8R7aTdV6EcxGQ02s1BjQ6YUgQFEklaPhpluZ/fBOkk/tZ8JrRSfqyMEdcGkAlQQNS9cS3rYROxn7GUYcY8AJLagFksDRd5CPnkROfYLWyqgxZJbfT2rjXsrJRhgtId/0QmgRJ4G7ejMm3Qj1WKmNfHVsPMEBBn9G+z8mfHcLsvcRmCqgIaSXrUHW9RKEIL8cQc99DeKQvLkDae9E/UhpaKc9tVc8qQYw1NbF8KJu/FPHkQ83QKWIBjXS3c9iWldCGZwT+1AviyQ87IIHotePGdbGnoYWmAK6ttLyymHmv/wdTs+LcPIn6H8NvBxOKo+sfCJS9PsJtHgeELxFdyNOBAxt7KkxcTlUoWFxNxKXXWrpfdHGgS/Q8kiUW7I22jt+CR0fBIREy7LIu7ikjAHXFZx6AGSAw3tg4RpwXPi+DzLgTAxC8TyIIIEPCmIUqYxCZRTxx6OrA/UAXMGRr9Zzy5yMc3RFs852VcGNtQZ65fMQZ0Y7xi00M0eIMcLpMRkbqYR3ugnLhZFSuOuMZfcNGSTrxg0tgLkKNJ2/Klc2UKioFn3d5SoXJK5Q5+17WT+vgU6uM4ar/LClnwNAKJHLpFTVv17gdIhIGqj9BQBF07VXMETuAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
                  Item3</label>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <label>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
                  Item4</label>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <label>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
                  Item5</label>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <label>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
                  Item6</label>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <label>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
                  Item7</label>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="mr-button">
      <label><span>Menu2</span></label>
      <div class="submenu">
         <div class="column">
            <ul class="cat_parent">
               <li>
                  <label>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
                  Item 2-1</label>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a valid *doctype* fixes this for IE8, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Oterwise IE will be rendering the page in [*Quirks mode*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and the [CSS child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) `ul#mrmenu li:hover>.submenu` that you use to show the menu will not work. *Note: CSS descendant selectors will still work in Quirks Mode.*

Comment: Attached is a standalone HTML file with embedded CSS that with minor edits works in IE8, but when merged into a larger WordPress site it wouldn't work. this is to fix the actual Wordpress site, not the HTML file - but you can have a look for an idea.
here site [link](http://trondheim360.com)

Comment: The site linked is working for me in IE8. The site seems to freeze after loading (very likely to be my firewall) but after browser becomes responsive again, the top menu hover is working. I can try later from another machine outside the firewall later.